# CSS Horizontal Controls in Header

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am having difficulties to align two elements horizontally, which makes me feel dumb, I tried sth I used to do but none of them worked.

How can I put that submit button next to the text field, horizontally without breaking anything?

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vv57k/2/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want something like that http://jsfiddle.net/vv57k/6/

to place them inline you must wrap the text input in another div, data-inline is not working with input text, because it creates a container (like for select ..)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
#searchField {
   width: 70%;
   float:left;   
}
#searchButton {
   width: 25%;
   float:right;   
}
```

Might not be the best method but it works. You might want to add a bit of padding too, just to tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vv57k/3/

U may have to fix the width in px if you are sure about where and how u are using this. I have added in percentage